# How do I capitalize the common letters of two words?

Tags: java

Problem:
Write a program that takes two words as input and finds any common letters that they have. For example, the words ‘computer’ and ‘program’ have the letters ‘o’, ‘m’, ‘p’, and ‘r’ in common.  The input to the program will be a string which contains two words consisting solely of lowercase alphabetic characters and separated by a single space. Output the words with all common letters capitalized.

Sample Input and Output:
Input two words: computer program
cOMPuteR PROgRaM

I am new to java and I have tried everything I know to solve this problem, which is next to nothing. Can you help me?

This is what I've got so far

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    //User input
    System.out.println("Please input two words. \nExample: computer program");
    String input = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();

    //Split the user's input
    String[] inputWords = input.split(" ");
    String firstWord = inputWords[0];
    String secondWord = inputWords[1];

    String commonLettersCaps = capitalizeCommonLetters(firstWord, secondWord);

}

private static String capitalizeCommonLetters(String firstWord, String secondWord) {

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Not tested the code yet but here is an idea: convert 2 input into char array, then loop through every char in first array, find if there are matches in the second array, if they do, uppercase the current 2 indexes.

```
char[] firstWordArr = firstWord.toCharArray();
char[] secondWordArr = secondWord.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < firstWordArr.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < secondWordArr.length; j++) {
        if (firstWordArr[i] == secondWordArr[j]) {
            firstWordArr[i] = Character.toUpperCase(firstWordArr[i]);
            secondWordArr[j] = Character.toUpperCase(secondWordArr[j]);
        }
    }
}
return new String(firstWordArr) + " " + new String(secondWordArr);
```

In the if condition, you can replace it with `Character.toUpperCase(firstWordArr[i]) == Character.toUpperCase(secondWordArr[j])` if you would like to perform comparision without case sensitive.

Comment: Your runtime is `O(n^2)`. There is an `O(n)` solution.

Comment: Yes it is O(n^2), but OP question did not mention about complexity of the program.

Comment: @LoMaPh The posted solution is easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

This works.  I tried to cut down on redundant processing as much as possible, but I have to believe there is a more optimum solution.  This is pretty straightforward with comments in the code.

Note that ANDing a character with `~040` turns off the bit that differentiates lower case and upper case (thus making it upper case).

```
String s1 = "computer";
String s2 = "program";

// find the characters common to both
// strings.

// processed characters are marked
// to avoid redundant processing

StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
boolean[] processed = new boolean[256];
for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
    char c = s1.charAt(i);

    // ignore if this character has been checked
    if (!processed[c]) {
        if (s2.indexOf(c) >= 0) {
            //save common character
            sb1.append(c);
        }
    }
    // mark character as processed
    processed[c] = false;
}
// A string of the common characters
String common = sb1.toString();

char sa[] = s1.toCharArray();
char sb[] = s2.toCharArray();

// Now go thru and change the common
// characters to upper case
for (int i = 0; i < sa.length; i++) {
    if (common.indexOf(sa[i]) >= 0) {
          sa[i] &= ~040;
    }
}
// Ditto
for (int i = 0; i < sb.length; i++) {
    if (common.indexOf(sb[i]) >= 0) {
        sb[i] &= ~040;
    }
}

System.out.println(new String(sa));
System.out.println(new String(sb));
```

prints

```
cOMPuteR
PROgRaM
```